# How to return struct in Rust without 'use of moved value' error?

Tags: struct, rust, clone, influxdb, serde

I think the problem I'm running into with this code is that the struct I'm trying to return has variables that are strings.
Currently I am querying an InfluxDB database and storing the result in the `result` variable. The print line towards the bottom of my function confirms that the index it correctly and is printing

```
IotData { time: 2021-12-27T14:01:34.404593Z, device_id: "1000", transaction_date: "27-12-2021", transaction_time: "14:01:34", usage: 8 }
```

How do I return this struct? I added the `Clone` attribute to the struct and return the clone since I encountered the `has not attribute 'Copy'` error, but now I am receiving the error, `use of moved value: 'result'`. I am new to Rust and don't quite understand ownership. My next guess is that I need to add lifetimes to my function and return the reference instead, but am not sure where to go from here.

Code Dump:

```
use influxdb::{ Client, ReadQuery};
use chrono::{ Utc };
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
use serde_derive::{ Serialize, Deserialize };

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct IotData {
    time: chrono::DateTime<Utc>,
    device_id: String,      
    transaction_date: String,
    transaction_time: String,
    usage: i64,
}

pub async fn pull(last_time: u64) -> IotData {
    let client = Client::new("http://localhost:8086", "PuPPY");
    let query_text = format!("
        SELECT * 
        FROM device_data 
        WHERE time > {} 
        ORDER BY time 
        LIMIT 1", last_time);
    let read_query = ReadQuery::new(query_text);
    let result = client
        .json_query(read_query)
        .await
        .and_then(|mut db_result| db_result.deserialize_next::<IotData>()); 
    println!("{:?}", result.unwrap().series[0].values[0]); 
    return result.unwrap().series[0].values[0].clone();
}
```

Comment: Note that since Rust 2018 you don't need `extern crate` anymore.

Comment: What if you remove the `println!`? Will the return compile then?

Comment: @Cerberus Yes! Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Minimized example yielding the essentially same error:

```
pub fn pull<T: std::fmt::Debug>(opt: Option<T>) -> T {
    println!("{:?}", opt.unwrap());
    opt.unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5e56a64f1177a2773416bc2e51f11d1)
The error is this:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `opt`
   --> src/lib.rs:3:5
    |
1   | pub fn pull<T: std::fmt::Debug>(opt: Option<T>) -> T {
    |                                 --- move occurs because `opt` has type `Option<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
2   |     println!("{:?}", opt.unwrap());
    |                          -------- `opt` moved due to this method call
3   |     opt.unwrap()
    |     ^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `opt`
help: consider calling `.as_ref()` to borrow the type's contents
    |
2   |     println!("{:?}", opt.as_ref().unwrap());
    |                          +++++++++
```

(By the way, if you're reading your errors from IDE, you might not see most of this. That's the general advice: confusing compiler errors in IDE are usually more clear in console, where they are not trimmed)

Here, it's easy to see the issue: `Option::unwrap` [consumes `self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap), since that's the only way for it to yield the owned value. So, then we unwrap the incoming `Option` to print its contents, we destroy it for good - there's nothing more to return.

To fix it, we can do one of the following:

- Just follow the compiler suggestion and add `as_ref` before first `unwrap`. In this case, we will consume not the `Option<T>`, but only the shared reference to it, which can be freely used without touching the value.
- Remove the `println!`, since it seems to be purely debugging information anyway.
- Unwrap the `Option` once, and then use the unwrapped value twice:

```
pub async fn pull(last_time: u64) -> IotData {
    // --snip--
    let value = result.unwrap().series[0].values[0];
    println!("{:?}", value); 
    return value;
}
```

Note also that you don't really need `clone` in any case - again, `Option::unwrap` returns an owned value, so you don't have to clone it explicitly.